# Adding to i in a loop?

Tags: jquery

I have a loop:

```
for (var i in $quizData['answers']) {

    $(".question"+(parseInt(i)+1)+" a").text($quizData['answers'][i]['answer']);

};
```

In the loop I need to add a 1 to i, I have achieved this via parseInt, is there a better way?

Comment: You could do +i+1, but parseInt is safer.

Comment: you need to ensure that $quizData keys are numbers. If so, just use **(i+1)**

Comment: @KevinB `parseInt(x, 10)`, perhaps .. the lack of assumed decimal radix is something that JavaScript didn't get correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a loop, and then `i + 1` if the first `i` starts with 0:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $quizData.length; i++) {
    $(".question" + (i + 1) + " a").text($quizData['answers'][i]['answer']);
}
```

Comment: Based on his example, `i` doesn't need to start at 0 or even be sequential

Comment: I'll wager it is -- he just wants his classes to be 1-based instead of 0-based like the data.

Comment: i needs to start at 0 because my data starts at 0 but the class I am targeting for each piece of data starts at 1

Answer (score 0):

You code is completely fine. There are no "Better" way to do the same thing.

Objects' keys in javascript is always a string no matter how you define it.

For example:

```
var obj = { 1:"a", 2:"b"}
```

Will eventually end up as

```
{ "1":"a", "2":"b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

if $quizData['answers'] is an array, you can do

```
$quizData['answers'].forEach(function(element,i){
    $(".question"+(i+1)+" a").text(element['answer']);
});
```

The first parameter of the function is the element, and the second is the index of your array

Comment: This doesnt answer the question, the i in the loop needs to be +1

Comment: The i is the index of your array, you can add +1 to your i without any problem